# Can I generate repetitive code segements with a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to do something like the following:

```
Start of code
 Repetitive code line 1
 Repetitive code line 2
 Repetitive code line 3
 ......
 Repetitive code line n
End of code
```

So far I've tried putting a for-loop into a print statement:

```
strings2<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
print(paste("start of code",for(i in strings2){print(paste0("repetitive code line",i))},"end of code"))
```

However, the "Start of code" and "end of code"-lines turns up at the wrong place:

```
[1] "repetitive code linea"
[1] "repetitive code lineb"
[1] "repetitive code linec"
[1] "repetitive code lined"
[1] "repetitive code linee"
[1] "repetitive code linef"
[1] "repetitive code lineg"
[1] "start of code  end of code"
```

Can this be done with a for-loop, or is there a better way?

Comment: Instead of writing code to generate repetitive code, why not make the code less repetitive? This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are asking but I am not sure it is exactly what you want. For instance, I explicitly coded the starting and ending of the loop. Have a look.

```r
starting <- "start of code"
strings2 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
ending <- "end of code"

for (i in seq_along(strings2) ) {
  if (i == 1L) {
    print(starting)
  }
  print(strings2[i])
  if (i == length(strings2)) {
    print(ending)
  }
}
#> [1] "start of code"
#> [1] "a"
#> [1] "b"
#> [1] "c"
#> [1] "d"
#> [1] "e"
#> [1] "f"
#> [1] "g"
#> [1] "end of code"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: And of course you can replace `print(strings2[i])` with whatever code you want.